# PowerBI conditional/advanced filtering - is it possible?

Tags: powerbi, filtering

I have a large set of Equipment data that contains both geographical equipment location and company ownership data.

The geographical data has a hierarchy based on size (i.e. continent, country, county, city, street), so the filters for that data is easy.

The company data details which companies own which pieces of equipment, but it’s not directly related to geography, so multiple companies can own equipment on a single site.  So I can filter by company name nicely.

As the data is common to both company and location, I’d like to combine in to one dashboard, but with two filters. I’d love to be able to filter by location OR filter by Company but ideally, I don’t want the users to try to use both filters at the same time.  Is it possible to have some logic built in so that if a user selects a location filter, it clears any Company filters selected and vice versa so that if a user selects a company filter any location filters already selected are cleared.

Is this possible and if so, how would I go about it?

Thanks in advance,
Dofus

Answer (score 0):

Using [buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-buttons?tabs=powerbi-desktop) and [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks?tabs=powerbi-desktop) you can clear filters and toggle the visibility of slicers.